# Can I cast B to C if B and C extends the same abstract class A?

Tags: java

The code looks like

```
public abstract class A {
    protected int a;
    public A() {}
    public A(int _a) {
        this.a = _a;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {}
    public B(int _a) {
        super(_a + 1);
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    public C() {}
    public C(int _a) {
        super(_a);
    }
    public int getA() {
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

And what I did is to cast B to C, which didn't work for me:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A b = new B(2);
        System.out.println(((C)b).getA());
    }
}
```

Could I cast B to C if they extends the same abstract class?

Comment: Why not simply try it out?

Comment: All classes extend `Object`, still you can not cast each class to each other class.

Comment: @Ipy: And what did you conclude from that message? Honestly, you shouldn't have asked this question. You already know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

The metaphor would be :

```
public abstract class Animal {
    protected int age;
    public A() {}
    public A(int _age) {
        this.age = _age;
    }
}

public class Bulldog extends Animal {
    public Bulldog() {}
    public Bulldog(int _age) {
        super(_age + 1);
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {}
    public Cat(int _age) {
        super(_age);
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return this._age;
    }
}
```

You wouldn't take a 7-year old Bulldog and pretend it's a 7-year old Cat. Neither javac nor PETA would approve.

Answer (score 1):

No. Each class can add its own methods so class `C` can have `specialMethod` while class `B` may not have it. If such casting would be possible you would be able to try to invoke this `specialMethod` on instance of `B` which wouldn't be OK.

Rule of thumb is: you can cast vertically, not horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

No, you could not. B and C is not related.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to answer yourself such questions you need to always ask the **"is a"** question.

- Can you cast `B` to `A` ? -> Is `B` an `A` ? -> **Yes (because it extends A)**
- Can you cast `C` to `A` ? -> Is `C` an `A` ? -> **Yes (because it extends A)**
- Can you cast `B` to `C` ? -> Is `B` a `C` ? -> **No (because it does not extend or implement C)**

Answer (score 0):

It is **syntactically** correct. But it might give a problem during **runtime**.
Here's a similar case :
Both `Vector` and `ArrayList` implement `List`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    Vector b = (Vector) l;
    b.copyInto(new Object[5]); (ArrayList doesn't have method copyInto)
}
```

Compiles fine..
Error during Runtime :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

If class `A` extends class `B`, you can say `A is a B` - that's called polymorphism.

In your example, `B` is an `A`, and `C` is an `A` - so you can call `B` an `A`, and `C` an `A`.
The compiler can just do that, there is no need of an explicit cast.

By example, using a `List` with `A`s, you are able to store `B`s and `C`s into it.
But `A` don't have to be a `B` (it could be a `C` instead), so you have to tell the compiler to handle it as such by doing an explicit cast.